# Горизонтальная прокрутка блока мышью

Tags: прокрутка, mousewheel

Как можно реализовать горизонтальную прокрутку DIVа колёсиком мыши при наведении на него?

Может есть конкретное решение (готовый код)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колесико мышки и прочие устройства-указатели могут генерировать события как вертикальной прокрутки, так и горизонтальной. Нижеприведённый сценарий на JavaScript подменяет вертикальную прокрутку на горизонтальную, игнорируя настройки последней. То есть элемент всегда прокручивается вбок настолько же, насколько он бы прокрутился по вертикали. Вертикальная прокрутка будет отключена, поэтому желательно, чтобы содержимое блока помещалось бы в своих границах.

```js
document.getElementById("horizontal-scroller")
  .addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    if (event.deltaMode == event.DOM_DELTA_PIXEL) {
      var modifier = 1;
      // иные режимы возможны в Firefox
    } else if (event.deltaMode == event.DOM_DELTA_LINE) {
      var modifier = parseInt(getComputedStyle(this).lineHeight);
    } else if (event.deltaMode == event.DOM_DELTA_PAGE) {
      var modifier = this.clientHeight;
    }
    if (event.deltaY != 0) {
      // замена вертикальной прокрутки горизонтальной
      this.scrollLeft += modifier * event.deltaY;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```html
<pre id="horizontal-scroller" style="overflow:auto">
йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен
йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен
йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен йцукен
</pre>
```